# Passing list of search string in contains in FilterExpression

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Is there any way to pass a list of search strings in the contains() method of FilterExpression in DynamoDb?

Something like below:

```
search_str = ['value-1', 'value-2', 'value-3']
result = kb_table.scan(
            FilterExpression="contains (title, :titleVal)", 
            ExpressionAttributeValues={ ":titleVal": search_str }
        )
```

For now I can only think of looping through the list and scanning the table multiple times (as in below code), but I think it will be resource heavy.

```
for item in search_str:
    result += kb_table.scan(
            FilterExpression="contains (title, :titleVal)", 
            ExpressionAttributeValues={ ":titleVal": item }
        )
```

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

For the above scenario, the `CONTAINS` should be used with `OR` condition. When you give array as input for `CONTAINS`, DynamoDB will check for the SET attribute ("SS", "NS", or "BS"). It doesn't looks for the sub-sequence on the string attribute.

> If the target attribute of the comparison is of type String, then the
>   operator checks for a substring match. If the target attribute of the
>   comparison is of type Binary, then the operator looks for a
>   subsequence of the target that matches the input. If the target
>   attribute of the comparison is a set ("SS", "NS", or "BS"), then the
>   operator evaluates to true if it finds an exact match with any member
>   of the set.

**Example:-**

```
movies1 = "MyMovie"
movies2 = "Big New"
fe1 = Attr('title').contains(movies1)
fe2 = Attr('title').contains(movies2)

response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=fe1 or fe2        
    )
```

Comment: yes, target attribute here is String.. sorry i did not understand what you meant by using `CONTAINS with OR`, could you please elaborate

Comment: ok that makes it clear... but in my scenario we cannot tell how many items will be there, we will have a variable list containing some string values, any workaround that you can think of?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no workaround for this scenario. Even creating the indexes wouldn't help here. Even if you create the index with title as partition key, you can't use contains on Query api key attribute. Batch get item can't be used as well with Contains.

Comment: one last que: which one is better for this scenario- `scan` or `query with an Id search followed by FilterExpression`

Comment: It depends on the number of items present in the table. If the number of items is very small, then scan should be fine. Otherwise, Query API should be used wherever possible. It will reduce the cost. Though, I am not sure how you have got the Ids (i.e. partition key data).

Answer (score 0):

a little bit late but to allow people to find a solution i give here my method.
lets assume that in your DB you have a props called 'EMAIL you want to filter your scan on this EMAIL with a list of value. you can proceed as following.

```
list_of_elem=['mail1@mail.com','mail2@mail.com','mail3@mail.com']
#set an empty string to create your query
stringquery=""
# loop each element in your list
for index,value in enumerate(list_of_elem):
    # add your query of contains with mail value
    stringquery=stringquery+f"Attr('EMAIL').contains('{value }')"
    # while your value is not the last element in list add the 'OR' operator
    if index < len(list_of_elem)-1:
        stringquery=stringquery+ ' | '
 dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
 # Use eval of your query string to parse the string as filter expression
 tableUser = dynamodb.Table('mytable')
     tableUser.scan(
     FilterExpression=eval(stringquery) 
     )
```